# Inserting data using arrays within a loop of unspecified number of input fields

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Here is the code that displays the table in a form where you are to insert manually only the last field.

After filling you should go ahead and save the form into the database, but since there are no specific number of input fields (as they will vary), I need to use an array to capture all the data.

```
$quam = mysqli_query('select * from locstock where loccode="' . $loc . '"') or die(mysqli_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($quam)) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . getItemcode($row['itemid']) . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . getItemname($row['itemid']) . '</td>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . ($row['itemid']) . '" name="itemid[0][]">';
        echo '<td>' . ($row['quantity']) . '</td>';
        echo '<input type="hidden" value="' . ($row['quantity']) . '" name="iquant[0][]">';
        echo '<td><input type="text" title="Enter Manual Count" placeholder="Enter Manual Count" name="tally[0][]"></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
```

How can I retrieve the data?

Comment: You can just check the $_POST variables in the $_POST page? using print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily `count()` your `INPUT` fields data. as your values are part of array -> `name="iquant[0][]"` you can easily process them. See output of `print_r($_POST);` after submitting your form.